# How to use BitBucket with VS Code?

Tags: git, bitbucket, visual-studio-code

I am using `Bitbucket` as my Remote repository. My IDE is VS Code. I am now developing flutter projects.

Can someone please explain me, step by step, how I can push and pull code from VS Code to BitBucket?

I have installed their plugin and all, but I can't figure out how. Every online tutorial, including Atlassian official, seems to be confusing and half baked.

I am on Mac. Git is installed as a part of Flutter installation process.

Answer (score 13):

1. Create a new repository in bitbucket
2. Clone this in new project in VSC - folder is created automatically
   You will need to insert the remote repository, something like https://something@bitbucket.org/myname/guestbook.git
   [image]
3. Make changes. Or copy an existing project, but leave the .git directory unchanged!
4. Commit
5. push

Answer (score 7):

I've been wondering the same and spent most of the day trying!!!

I've managed to do part of it in the end. Definitely not the "best practice" approach but might help you get started (if you're on Windows).

**First follow the steps here in terms** of setting up SSH Keys in VS Code/BitBucket  . Definitely a pre-requisite for VS Code to recognize your SSH Keys connected to your BitBucket account

- From Bitbucket perspective: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh3
- From VS Code perspective: https://www.cgranade.com/blog/2016/06/06/ssh-keys-in-vscode.html

**Then, Install the Bitbucket and JIRA Extension:**

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atlassian.atlascode
  Detailed instructions here on how to set-up
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/install-atlassian-for-vs-code-969520759.html
  Once done, do not forget (in VS Code) to login to Bitbucket

Then...

1. Create your empty repo in Bitbucket. Copy both the SSH and HTTPS Clone Git instruction (click on the CLONE button on the right-hand side when you're on the "Source" folder in Bitbucket Cloud).
2. Select the Terminal tab in VS Code (View -> Output/Terminal). Navigate to the directory under which you want to create your repo locally (do not create a folder for your repo; that will be created automatically) and paste your GIT clone instruction => It should work and clone your (empty project). If it fails for some SSH Keys, use the HTTPS Clone instruction.

Milestone 1: At this stage an empty folder with the name of your repo should be created and have the .git subfolder.

From there you can...

1. code away
2. use the "Source Control" menu on the left hand-side of VS code navigation bar to see files pending and commit your changes

I got stuck at the "push" part trying to use the *Source Control* menus. Kept getting an error about  origin.

As I'm really useless with GIT I reverted to SourceTree to push my changes. But at least all the basic work in VS Code and finally get all my code in the repo on BitBucket cloud. I'm sure there is a git command to set the origin using the terminal but don't have patience.

Comment: It's the same for me. I can push only from the terminal after starting ssh-agent and adding the private key to it. Remote actions (i.g. push/pull) don't work with VS Code git ui.

Answer (score 2):

Try following steps,

1. Create a new repository in bitBucket
2. Copy, clone URL
3. Open the VS code  and Click "New Window" in the File menu
4. Click "clone repository" under Start in the Welcome window or in the source control tab
5. Paste clone URL
6. Select the location folder (don't create the project folder manually, it will be
   created automatically)
7. A window open for authentication
8. Now you can add new files or copy existing one
9. In the "Terminal" menu click new terminal

   In  the new terminal  set following git command

   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
10. After changes, commit
11. Now push

Answer (score 1):

If by "using BitBucket" you mean setting up a local repository from an existing BitBucket repo, I found [this BitBucket tutorial](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/#SetupanSSHkey-ssh3) to be pretty straightforward and self-explanatory. I tried it and was able to clone, edit, commit, push, etc.

You may need to update your `user.email` and can do so with `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If your git password was required by the source control system,

1. Sign in to the bitbucket
2. Go to Personal Setting > ACCESS MANAGEMENT
3. App passwords > Create app password

When source control asks for a password, you can use the created password as your git password.

Please double-check that you already have these configs.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Go to your bitbucket branch
2. Click "Clone" on the left hand side, a small window will pop-up
   [See the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en7yY.png)
3. Clone the "SSH" URL.
4. Go to your VS Code Start window and click "clone repository", now paste the copied link and select a folder for your repo.
5. After opening the cloned folder you should be able to access your branches